# answer incoming skype call using skype4com in c#

Tags: c#, skype4com

can any one guide me how to answer a skype call using skype4com in c#.
Currently i am generating an event when there is an incoming call and it is working well but i dont know how to answer that call... Thanks in advance for any help

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using SKYPE4COMLib;
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
private static extern long mciSendString(string strCommand, StringBuilder strReturn,   int iReturnLength, IntPtr oCallback);


  skype.CallStatus += new _ISkypeEvents_CallStatusEventHandler(Skype_checkincoming);
  public void Skype_checkincoming(Call call, TCallStatus status)
        {

        try
        {
            if ((call.Type == TCallType.cltIncomingP2P)
                || (call.Type == TCallType.cltIncomingPSTN))
            {

                if (status == TCallStatus.clsRinging)
                {



                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() + ": " +
             "Call Status Event Fired - Failed" +
             " - Exception Source: " + e.Source + " - Exception Message: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem with

```
  call.Answer();
```

?